# Crashlytics crashing when logging

Tags: java, android, crash, crashlytics

I recently updated Crashlytics in my android app to v. 2.9.4. Since then, I started seeing errors on some devices, when trying to log some information:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.singleton (Fabric.java:275)
at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.getKit (Fabric.java:525)
at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.getInstance 
(Crashlytics.java:188)
at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.checkInitialized 
(Crashlytics.java:371)
at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.log (Crashlytics.java:230)
```

The log is called in another module, like:

```
Crashlytics.log(Log.DEBUG, "ISA", "Some log");
```

The main module initializes Crashlytics in the main entry point, right in onCreate, after calling `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`:

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

The issue appears only on some devices (1/100). Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I've never problems with Fabric with this. In my opinion you have wrong initialized Fabric.

Fabric should be initialized in `Application` class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain why it should be initialized in Application rather than main activity onCreate?

Comment: @user1592546 because that's what the Fabric documentation says.

Comment: @DennyDog I don't see it in the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started

Comment: @ClassA Fabric is the old one. Firebase Crashlytics is the newest.

Comment: @androiddeveloper Yes, but this question is related to fabric crashlytics. Also, fabric is still usable till next year.

Comment: @ClassA Wait, by "till next year", you mean it will stop working after that?

Comment: @androiddeveloper yes fabric is moving to firebase, all users should migrate before then - https://get.fabric.io/roadmap

Comment: @ClassA Interesting, but what will happen to apps that use it, and aren't updated to use Firebase? Will it still work for them?

Comment: @androiddeveloper I'm not sure if the Fabric website will close. Currently, after you have migrated, your data is available in Google crashlytics and Fabric. So I guess that older apps will still be able to use Fabric, as long as the website stays up.

Comment: It doesn't say about whether it will stop working. Only about what will work. There are clues though : "Bid farewell to Fabric" , "We'll support Fabric until" ... I think it will stop working. Hopefully won't cause a lot of apps to crash.

Comment: MARCH 31, 2020
Bid farewell to Fabric - from the link.